# How to Linq select Model class Bind data in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, rest

How to Linq select Model class Bind data in VB.net

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to read a Xml file with <Key,Value> . Using that key value used for further model class selection   suppose <scope> <name="abc" value="asd per "> <name="qwe" value="qwe rty "></scope>   This type of Xml File read and user defined condition match key is used for selection that value , so need to bind that key and value with model class    eg. class XMLClassName  { dim FieldName  as string {get;set;} dim  ValueName  as string {get;set;}} this class bind with xml <key,value> in VB.net using linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim xe() As XMLClassName = xd.Descendants().Elements().Select(Function(n) New XMLClassName With {.FieldName = n.Attribute("Name").Value, .ValueName = n.Attribute("Value").Value}).ToArray()
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.